# Characteristic Function of Gamma Distributed Random Variables

Tags: characteristic-functions, gamma-distribution

I have the following characteristic function
$$\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{(is)^m}{m!} \sigma_{m,k} \frac{\Gamma(\beta + m)}{\Gamma(\beta)},$$
where $i$ is the imaginary unit, $\beta>0$, $\Gamma(\cdot)$ is the Gamma function and
$$\sigma_{m,k} \equiv \frac{\Gamma(\beta+\alpha)\Gamma(\beta+k)}{\Gamma(\beta + m)\Gamma(\beta + \alpha + k)},$$
where $k$ can be any non-negative integer and $\alpha > 0$ is another parameter.  If there exists a $\sigma_k > 0$ (a positive constant that does not depend on $m$, but can depend on $k$), such that
$$(\star) \qquad \qquad \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{(is)^m}{m!} \sigma_{m,k} \frac{\Gamma(\beta + m)}{\Gamma(\beta)} = \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{(is)^m}{m!} \sigma_{k}^m \frac{\Gamma(\beta + m)}{\Gamma(\beta)}$$
then I know that the left hand side is the characteristic function of a Gamma distributed random variable with shape parameter $\beta$ and scale parameter $\sigma_k$, since the right hand-side is.

**My Question**: is it possible to show that there exists a $\sigma_k$ so that $(\star)$ is true?  Is there some form of intermediate value theorem that I can appeal to here?  Note that the sequence $\sigma_{0,k}, \sigma_{1,k}, ...$ is a decreasing sequence.